# `rake db:migrate` fails with a NoMethodError

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

So everything has worked on my project to this point which is 6.0 Adding a second model.  I did

`rails generate model Comment commenter:string body:text     article:references`

And this generated the correct files which I opened and looked at.
  `app/models/comment.rb`
And the migrate file 
  `_create_comments.rb` (I left off the date stamp)

When I run rake `db:migrate` I get the following errors:

```
 == 20150709191058 CreateComments: migrating ===================================
-- create_table(:comments)
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

private method `test' called for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::TableDefinition:0x007fe7984adf58>/Users/johnlarkin/Sites/blog/db/migrate/20150709191058_create_comments.rb:5:in `block in change'
/Users/johnlarkin/Sites/blog/db/migrate/20150709191058_create_comments.rb:3:in `change'
NoMethodError: private method `test' called for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::TableDefinition:0x007fe7984adf58>
/Users/johnlarkin/Sites/blog/db/migrate/20150709191058_create_comments.rb:5:in `block in change'
/Users/johnlarkin/Sites/blog/db/migrate/20150709191058_create_comments.rb:3:in `change'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Has anybody run into a similar error when working on this project  I've just started learning ruby and rails.

Thanks for your help.

```
class CreateComments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :comments do |t|
      t.string :commenter
      t.test :body
      t.references :article, index: true

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_foreign_key :comments, :articles
  end
end
```

Comment: Sounds like you probably have a typo in your migration file. Please show us the contents of "db/migrate/20150709191058_create_comments.rb".

Comment: Ok but how could I have a typo in the migration file I created it when I ran the generate model Comment ?

Comment: Please add it to the question itself.

Comment: I think you typed "test" instead of "text" in the rails generate command. You could remove all the new files and start over, or change "t.test" to "t.text".

Comment: Sorry I still having problems posting code to the forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you typed "test" instead of "text" in the rails generate command. You could remove all the new files and start over, or change "t.test" to "t.text".